# Postfix evaluation within atomic CAS

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

First question, Why isn't the postfix evaluation (++) applied in the arguments in the atomic_compare_exchange_weak operation?  The value of a is the same before and after the operation.  However when used in printf(), as expected, the value is incremented.

The code:

```
int main(){
  atomic<int> s(0);
  int a = 0;
  atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&s,&a,a++);
  printf("%d %d\n",s.load(),a++);
  printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

has the following output:

```
0 0 
1
```

when I expected this output:

```
0 1
2
```

Secondly, I'd like to use the postfix evaluation to test the order of atomic operations in a multithreaded situation, is my approach here flawed in some tragic way? For example, even if the increment operator did work, could another CAS operation happen in between the first CAS and the increment evaluation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass a++ as the third argument, by the time the function call begins, a holds the incremented value (see [order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) ). 
Since that value no longer equals the value of the atomic, the C++ CAS reads from the atomic and writes to the second argument, which makes it appear as if the increment "didn't happen".

Check the value returned by the CAS.

Comment: So, if I wanted to make sure the increment of a and the CAS of s happened sequentially, would I need to use a lock?

And thanks, the original code was incorrect.

Comment: @MattPennington `atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&s, &a, a + 1); a++;` should work right?

Comment: @Tavian, I'd like the CAS and the increment to happen without the possibility of being interrupted by another thread... I didn't include multiple threads in order to keep the example concise.  So in this example, yes that would be correct, but I'd like both operations to happen "as one".

Comment: @MattPennington hard to tell what you need with a simplified example (this a isn't even shared). A lock would be an easy start.